# Salesforce1 click-to-dial can not return back to Salesforce1 until restarting the Salesforce1 app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, android

Follow the instruction from the official article (http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221658) to create a visualforce page as below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" docType="html-5.0" title="Call Contact">
  <a href="tel: {!Contact.Phone}" target="_blank">Phone: {!Contact.Phone}</a><br/>
</apex:page>
```

It works as it should be in the Salesforce1 app, but just one thing weird is that there is no way to return back to Salesforce1. The only way I can find is to stop and restart the Salesforce1 app.

Does anyone have idea for the issue?

**Screen1 - Click the quick action button "Click to dial"** - The action is linked to the visualforce of which the code is pasted as above.

[image]

**Screen2 - Click the link to dial**

[image]

**Screen3 - the dialer selector is started**

[image]

**Screen4 - select to use phone to dial**

[image]

**Screen5 - the phone dialer is now started**

[image]

**Screen6 - after the call** When click "return" then it will display home screen. In other words, the salesforce1 app is closed. Then, I check the **Recent Apps** and find the phonebook is now embedded in the Salesforce1, but there is no exit to go back to Salesforce1 app.

[image]

The only way to go back to the contact is to stop the Salesforce1 app and restart it again. Very stupid, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain that this will make a difference, but one "seemingly" small thing I see that you're doing which differs from the documentation is that you've inserted `phone:` in your code between `target="_blank">` and `{!Contact.Phone}` where the documentation would have only used:

```
<a href="tel: {!Contact.Phone}" target="_blank">{!Contact.Phone}</a>
```

I'd recommend you remove this since it's part of your href link, which I'd exect could easily cause an issue with the connection protocols (as in a fault or error of some kind) just like an invalid url or url parameter would cause a problem finding or loading a web page, assuming it could load it at all. In days past, the right combination of illegal characters would frequently crash a browser.

Additionally, I noticed the following caveats at the bottom of the link you provided. Have you confirmed the issue only appears with just your cell phone as opposed to someone else's too? You'll want to test your app with a variety of devices.

> Applications installed on your device hi-jacking the tel: URL scheme 
>   ... are not within Salesforce.com's control from the tel URL scheme and are usually device dependent. For more information please reach out to your relevant device OS provider on any additional programmatic options that you can avail of around the URL scheme or other applications.